# Exercise 10, Chapter IV, Serge Lang

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the inhomogeneous system
$$x'(t) = Ax(t) + b(t)$$
with $A \in M(n)$ and $b$ a continuous function. Show that the solution of this system, with $x(0) = x_{0}$ is
$$ x(t) = \text{e}^{tA} x_{0} + \text{e}^{tA}\int_{0}^{t}\text{e}^{-sA}b(s)ds $$
**this part I managed to show**.

**However, the exercise asks for more:**
show that there is a unique periodic solution (of period $2\pi$) for the case $b(t) = (0, \text{cos}(t))$ and
$$
A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1   \\
-k & -b 
\end{array}
\right]
$$
with $b,k > 0$.

I didn't get that part.

Comment: Would it help if you write the ODE as $\ddot x(t) = -k\dot x(t)+bx(t)+\cos(t)$?

Comment: Just curious, which of Lang's books are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $b(t)=\binom{0}{\cos t}$ which is periodic with period $2\pi$, the system has a particular solution with form
$$ x_p=\binom{c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t}{c_3\cos t+c_4\sin t} \tag1$$
with period $2\pi$.
Suppose that there is another particular solution $y_p$ with period $2\pi$. Then
$$x_p^{'}(t) = Ax_p(t) + b(t), y_p^{'}(t) = Ay_p(t) + b(t). $$
So
$$ (x_p-y_p)'=A(x_p-y_p)$$
which gives
$$ x_p-y_p=e^{At}(x_p(0)-y_p(0)) $$
or
$$ x_p=y_p+e^{At}(x_p(0)-y_p(0)). \tag2$$
With $A=(\matrix{0&1\\-k&-b})$, $e^{-At}$ is not periodic or constant. If $x_p(0)\neq y_p(0)$, then $x_p$ will not be periodic from (2), which is against the assumption (1).

Comment: How do you know? The whole point is to understand the exponential of that particular $A$, is it not?

Comment: That's right. $A$ is the key.